# Weird behaviour CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, swift

I try to animate an UILabel:

```
let label: UILabel = UILabel()
var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -150)
    self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
    self.label.transform = self.transform
})
```

It works well. I have a button and I added a selector so that when it is pressed, the label animates again:

```
func performSearch() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -300)
        self.label.transform = self.transform
    })
}
```

But what it actually does is to scale down the label as in the original state, move it down to the bottom of the screen, then animate, although all I want it to do is to move up. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforms can be a little confusing... Because you have *scaled* the transform, further transforms seem to be "auto-adjusted" by the scaling, but not in a really intuitive or obvious way.

This may help you get further:

```
// initial animation
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
    self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: -150)
    self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
    self.label.transform = self.transform
})

// "resuming" animation
func performSearch() {
    let distance: CGFloat = -300 / 2
    self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: distance)
    self.label.transform = self.transform

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: distance)
        self.label.transform = self.transform
    })


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain, please, why did your code work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move it up in performSearch() you need to use a positive y value:

```
self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the coordinate system to behave like iOS like this...

```
layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```